# C# change app language programmatically UWP realtime

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

In my application for each language string resources are stored separately and are displayed depending of type of language environment. I want to change the language in the application settings. How do I realize that after the language selection instantly apply it in the user interface?

Comment: Set [CurrentUICulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx) property when app launch.

Comment: I know that. But I need to change the language without restarting instantly. We need to change it right into the running application.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

We can use [ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.primarylanguageoverride.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) to change the language during runtime without restart the app.

For example: I have two languages supported "en" and "fr", localized message will show up in textblock.

1. Add using Windows.Globalization;
2. Change the default language from "en" to "fr" by

   ```
   ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "fr";
   ```
3. Re-navigate to the current page to refresh the UI.

   ```
   Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
   ```

Note that, you need to compare the PrimaryLanguageOverride with the system culture to set the language for next app launch, because the PrimaryLanguageOverride setting is persisted. And if you have page cache enabled, when you apply a different language on the fly, you need to clear the cache by setting `Frame.CacheSize = 0;` first then set it back.

Comment: This solution works for me every time but the first language change. After the first language change I have to manually click on an navigation element in order to load a page with the new language. For every language change after that the page refreshes automatically with the correct language.
This behavior even occurs when changing the CachSize as advised.

Comment: @ThisWillDoIt Did you find any solution for that issue? Otherwise, reporting this as bug might be the best idea...!?

Comment: I got another app working properly and compared them against each other. I still have no idea why this behavior occurs in on of the apps (https://github.com/theWalli/EurekaRemake).   


If I decide to report it after another round of checking on my side, where would be the best/official place to do so?

Comment: It can be solved by resetting the ResourceContext in the contructor, idk why though

Comment: Hi, how about refresh the UserControl to update newest language? My Signin layout is usercontrol :(

Comment: Using Frame.Navigate i get memory leakage issues. you dont?

Answer (score 15):

Some addition to Alan Yao's answer. There's one missing piece:
After you set the `Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride` and before re-navigating to the current page, you must call these two functions:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
```

This way you won't need the `Task.Delay()` workaround mentioned by Michael Woolsey.

One more important last step: when creating a Store package, you should make sure to set the "Generate app bundle" setting value to "Never". Reason from [this article](http://www.guruumeditation.net/en/dynamically-change-the-language-of-a-universal-app/):

> Because otherwise, it will create a bundle. It means that he will cut
>   your application into different parts to optimize the download. Only
>   the parts that are relevant for the devices will be downloaded. For
>   example, if there are the assets in different resolution, it will only
>   download the ones that are suitable for the device. Same thing for
>   languages, it will only download the resources file relevant to the
>   language of the device. So if you try to change language, it will fall
>   still fall back on the same base language, because others are not
>   installed.

Comment: Excellent reply, avoids workarounds that break UI fluidity (delay on UI thread).

Answer (score 4):

@ThisWillDoIt and @Herdo

I added a delay so that the "First" time it would work in my situation:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = languageCode;

await Task.Delay(100);

Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
```

Hope it helps work for you.

Comment: @Charlie Read Péter Bozsó answer above mine, that should answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [page MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.primarylanguageoverride.aspx) that describes the new feather about Language from Windows 8.1.

After modify the

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en-US";
```

I watched the property `resourceContext.Languages[0]` in order to launch the `PropertyChanged` event of my LanguageManager, which was a `StaticResources` declared in `App.xaml` with `x:Key = Loc`.

```
    private void ButtonEn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en-US";
        UpdateLang("en-US");
    }

    private async void UpdateLang(string newLang)
    {
        var resourceContext = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();

        while (true)
        {
            if (resourceContext.Languages[0] == newLang)
            {
                var loc = Application.Current.Resources["Loc"] as LanguagesManager;
                loc.ChangeLang();
                break;
            }
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
```

The `while (true)` was just for test, in fact it's better to escape by a "backup", because

> Those requirements may vary depending on the UI framework used by the app, and it may be necessary to restart the app.

Comment: Yes ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en-US"; should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of the above answers helped if `NavigationCacheMode` set to `"Required"` for the page. Here's the code that solved my problem.

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = language;
await Task.Delay(300);
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
rootFrame.Content = null;
rootFrame = null;            
rootFrame = new Frame();
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), null);
Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
```

Comment: Window.Current.Content as Frame got NULL