# Template 10 switch language setting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, template10

I have the following code in SettingsPage.xaml

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="LanguageSwitch" x:Uid="LanguageSwiich"
                                  Header="Switch language"
                                  Margin="2,130,0,0"
                                  IsOn="{Binding IsFullScreen, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  OffContent="English"
                                  OnContent="Franche"
                                  RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                  RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"  />
```

And added this into SettingsService.cs following codes just for testing

```
public bool IsEnglish
    {
        get { return _helper.Read<bool>(nameof(IsEnglish), true); }
        set
        {
            _helper.Write(nameof(IsEnglish), value);
            Views.Shell.HamburgerMenu.IsFullScreen = value;
        }
    }
```

And added this into SettingsPageViewModel.cs

```
public bool IsEnglish
    {
        get { return _settings.IsEnglish; }
        set
        {
            _settings.IsEnglish = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged();
            if (value)
            {
                var culture = new CultureInfo("fr");
                Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
            }
            else
            {
                var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            }
        }
    }
```

Is working for IsFullScreen but I want to make it to change language instead full screen.

Added last code into App.xaml.cs

```
var IsEnglish = _settings.IsEnglish;
```

So what I should change here in my code to make it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify you want to see English as the language only when the toggle is "true"?  Based on the code you shown at least what I am interpreting it shows that

//COPIED CODE from above

```
_settings.IsEnglish = value;
base.RaisePropertyChanged();
if (value)  // if true then do this...
{
    var culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
}
else  //not true aka FALSE
{
    var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
}
```

then French would be in the "True" state... otherwise "false" state English..

As for updating the ui at runtime you need to do something like the answer in this question [C# change app language programmatically UWP realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715690/c-sharp-change-app-language-programmatically-uwp-realtime)

writer in that answer also stated that restart of the application would be necessary.  I will also add unless you have the Resources files setup in the application simply changing the CultureInfo will not do anything unless you have the resources files with the translations in place... already reference x:Uid and how it can assist you in the globalization of the application.

Comment: Thanks, I want make a setting in SettingsPage.xaml, that users can change between 2 language. I cant figure the option to work for changing the language, that is my problem. Maybe it's better to make a dropdown that have 2 selecting 1 for English, 2nd for French, my problem is I can't figure this dropdown to that when a user select English change into English or if they choose French then changing into French. So have any idea how could man do that?

Comment: I have Resources files, and working fine if I change the code from var culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR") into var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

Comment: Above code is suspicious... Code is not symmetric between `true` and `false` cases. Also code does not check for an actual change so it would waste time if the property is set to the same value...

Comment: the above is exactly as it was above in OPs original post, I commented on very bad logic