# UWP MVVM: refresh page after change of language

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I have some code in my view model which changes the application language, which then changes the text on some of the controls.

This is the `DashboardViewModel`, which the Dashboard Page's data context is set to:

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = languageCode;
ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(DashboardPage));
```

With `NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(DashboardPage));` I tried to force the page to refresh, with no success. How would I do this?

Comment: Did you clear the page cache? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715690/c-sharp-change-app-language-programmatically-uwp-realtime

Comment: @IgorŠevo Yes, same result. The problem is that the `Navigate` method won't navigate to the same page. However, probably since I used the Windows Template Studio, the NavigationService.cs file is available to me, so I just added a different method which doesn't perform the "same page check" which the `Navigate` method does. I'm sure this isn't good practice, but it works. :-)

Answer (score 3):

this line works very well for me.

```
 await Task.Delay(100);
 Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it for me where Navigate was not repainting the frame.

Comment: Syncfusion Treeview will not refresh when nodes added in bound mode. This is a good quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

`NavigationService.Navigate()` is not doing anything if you're trying to navigate to the same page.

On workaround is to add a parameter to your navigation request to force it.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(DashboardPage), "force refresh after language change");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used an approach similar to @Vincent, but using `DateTime.Now.Ticks` as the parameter. This ensures that the value of the parameter is going to be different, which triggers the refresh.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(DashboardPage), DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
rootFrame?.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```