# UWP - Change of Languages

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp

I am trying to change a language at a UWP app so that the my x:uid objects related and my ResourceLoader based objects would change.
I am using, as recommended at other Q&A :

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = newLanguage;
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
```

However, everything that is controlled directly by the ResourceLoader is changed and whatever is created at the xaml with x:uid don't. If I change the language again then, x:uid changes to the previous language and the rest is at the new selected language.

I think that there might be something that is related to thread behavior for two reasons. First, a suggestion to fix it, that works, is to delay the thread before the navigation. Second, I have different behavior at virtual and physical machines (this bug happens at the physical machine obviously).

**I would really appreciate a solution or an explanation that allows good functionality that is not based on delaying threads.**

Some other related Q&As:

[UWP MVVM: refresh page after change of language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792071/uwp-mvvm-refresh-page-after-change-of-language/54787414?noredirect=1#comment96356071_54787414)

[C# change app language programmatically UWP realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715690/c-sharp-change-app-language-programmatically-uwp-realtime/54789012#54789012)

Thanks

Comment: I could reproduce this issue, I think it is relate to IO speed. may the  `x:uid`  is not ready. I will report this issue to related team.

Comment: Hey, thank you!
I reproduced it as well after I made some upgrades to my virtual machine.
As far as I understand the Reset() doesn't complete its work before I create the new thread with Frame.Navigate(..).
For now I am delaying based on a comparison of PrimaryLanguageOverride() and the language qualifier of ResourceContext..

Comment: Yep, In my opinion, `ApplicationLanguages` need to add the event handler for detecting `Reset` complete.

Comment: Same problem, any update about that?

Comment: So far the best solution I have is the one above.. Maybe @NicoZhu-MSFT has something new to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reported this issue, and currently there is a workaround that use delay after `Reset` method invoked. You could refer the following code.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static bool m_bFirstLanguageChangeNavigation = true;


async private void Show_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var context = ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
    var selectedLanguage = MyComboBox.SelectedValue;
    var lang = new List<string>();
    lang.Add(selectedLanguage.ToString());
    ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = selectedLanguage.ToString();
    ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
    ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();


    //added to work the first time
   if (m_bFirstLanguageChangeNavigation)
    {
       m_bFirstLanguageChangeNavigation = false;
       await Task.Delay(100);
    }


    Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());               
}
```