# NavigationViw Not Change Language According to PrimaryLanguageOverride

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I returned back to programming, long time ago, too many Changes.
I started with template studio and created a 3 Pages and settings , With A NavigaionView from a shell page,  MVVM light.
Now I can change themes, Adding New Language, and save settings.
When Change Language everything Change after reloading the Current page, Except the NavigationView Header and Menu Items Names, It only Changes after restart the Application.
Can any one help me How to force navigationView From ShellPage to refresh with new Language Settings?

this for SelectionChanged Event:

```
 private void CmbLanguage_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

  { string LanguageCode = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedValue as string;
    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = LanguageCode;
           Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());

 }
```

and this for binding from the ComboBox:

```
private Language _selectedLanguage;
public Language SelectedLanguage

{        
   get => _selectedLanguage;
   set
      {   _selectedLanguage = value;
          AppSett.PrimaryLanguageOverride = value.LanguageCode;
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = value.LanguageCode;
          RaisePropertyChanged();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue, if you want to show setting language without re-launch, you could set a delay before frame navigate.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;   
static bool m_bFirstLanguageChangeNavigation = true;

async private void Show_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var context = ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
    var selectedLanguage = MyComboBox.SelectedValue;
    var lang = new List<string>();
    lang.Add(selectedLanguage.ToString());
    ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = selectedLanguage.ToString();
    ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
    ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();


    //added to work the first time
   if (m_bFirstLanguageChangeNavigation)
    {
       m_bFirstLanguageChangeNavigation = false;
       await Task.Delay(100);
    }


    Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());               
}
```

For more please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56014807/7254781)

Comment: Already tried,this is just reload the Frame , i.e. All Pages Change Language, but the Elements of Navigation view (Header, Menu Items, ) Not Change until restart the Application

Comment: Have you add the `Task.Delay(100)`?

Comment: No, Just the pages inside the frame changed, but header and menu items, still with old language until , I restart the Application

Comment: it needs to reload the all navigationView , with Navigation start with Settings page

Comment: I check the app in the store that contains multiple language, both them need to restart after change the language. And the app toast a notification that tells user to restart the after change the language.