# Change language for dialog after overriding language?

Tags: c#, uwp, globalization

My code in MainPage.cs

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "ja-jp";
```

XAML

```
<Button content="Click" Click="Button_Click" />
```

after this i've opened dialog with my code

```
 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            {

                testDialog dialog = new testDialog();      
                await dialog.ShowAsync();

            }
        }
```

My testDialog's XAML code

```
 <TextBlock x:Uid="TestTextBlock" />
```

i've define the language's text in Resources.resw file, it worked fine if i put textblock in current MainPage but when i put it in dialog the textblock's text doesn't change, It only change after i reset the application. Any ideas how can i fix this guys ?'

Comment: "i reset the application" what you mean ?

Comment: i mean turn off the application and turn on.

Comment: try `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "ja-jp";` in `App.xaml.cs` file.

Comment: Any idea how can i change this dynamically ? i mean ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "value", value is a language which user choose from listbox. i dont want to put it in App.xaml.cs. Let me get this straight, i think UI didn't update after i overrided language so it only take affect after i reset the application.

Comment: this answer may help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32732141/5541998)

Comment: yeah i did follow that link and it working on my mainpage, i mean if i put textblock in the same page with ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride and Task.Delay it, but my textblock is in content dialog and it didn't working :(

Answer (score 1):

Setting new language:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "ja-jp";

Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
```

Reload Current page:

```
 private bool Reload(object param = null)
{
    var type = Frame.CurrentSourcePageType;

    try
    {
        return Frame.Navigate(type, param);
    }
    finally
     {
        Frame.BackStack.Remove(Frame.BackStack.Last());
     }

}
```

Also you can use `Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());` for refreshing current page UI.
please take a look at this post for more information: [Dynamically change the language of a universal app](http://www.guruumeditation.net/dynamically-change-the-language-of-a-universal-app/)

Comment: sorry, i've just comeback from work, this is not working cause this guy use message dialog in same mainpage and that is window phone, mine is open content dialog

Comment: Just for test, Try to get string resource from code behind for TextBlock . `ResourceLoader res = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();`  `myTextblock.Text = res.GetString("TestTextBlock.Text");`